# Create a picture viewer with image-selection capabilities

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple picture viewer that will allow the user to click a button and then select an image from the file system and have that image displayed in a JLabel.

I'm not familiar with picture viewing, but I've done file referencing before.

Comment: Is this homework?  Have you attempted it?

Answer (score 1):

(This question sounds like it could be homework, so I'm answering in a way that will point you in the right direction without simply giving away the answer.)

Have a look at the [`JLabel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(javax.swing.Icon)) constructor that takes an `Icon` parameter, and also the [`ImageIcon`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) class.

Comment: I understand how those would help me, but I'm trying to figure out how you would get the file from a file chooser

Comment: ok, so I'm getting this error:

sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
 at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon([path to image],[description]);

label.setIcon(icon);

Comment: I think I can get the image to show up using the ImageIcon class, but I'm not sure how to get the file path from a file chooser.